# Format Windows 7 without losing files/data

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I want to format my Windows 7 without losing my files. I currently have 2 hdd in my computer. 1 (Seagate Barracuda) is used for OS and another 1 (Western Digital) is just for my pictures, musics etc. Can I backup my files to the WD hdd and reinstall Windows 7 in the Seagate Barracuda hdd without losing data in the WD hdd?

Comment: You can copy almost all of your data to an external HD, reinstall Windows and then move the data back. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Just select the Seagate Barracuda drive during installation. Windows won't touch the Western Digital hard drive.

[image]

Above picture showing two identical hard drives to show that it is possible to select the correct drive without the need to unplug it physically to avoid confusion. Just make sure that at least one drive is labeled.

Comment: Maybe you even want to unplug the Western Digital for the installation process (just to be sure).

Comment: @Tim This is absolutely not necessary. This would only make sense if there were two drives of the same make and model and the user wasn't sure which is which.

Comment: You are right. It is indeed unnecessary. But especially when it comes to personal data I would prefer the extra safety layer (or even more to make a complete backup before).

Comment: Given the image in Ozn's answer, I'm tempted to agree with @Tim: unless the sizes are clearly very different, it might be hard to tell which is which?

Comment: @Arjan You're incorrect. Windows Vista/7 show the HDDs label on the installation screen making it perfectly easy to distinguish between drives. Also, you can switch to the command prompt during setup and check the content on each drive if you're really such a beginner who doesn't know his hardware.

Comment: @Zerobinary99: You can tell you're not one for taking detours by the way you circumvented the tedious task of typing 'list volume'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should choose just SB HDD for formatting.

[image]

Comment: In the above picture, can one tell which is the current Windows OS disk?

Comment: @Arjan YES! Disk 0 Partition 2... System Reserved can't be... Apart from its size that would barely offer enough space for Win95 it's a partition created by the system itself.

Comment: ...so, the question asker would see *three* options instead? (Two disks, one disk have that system and primary thing, and another disk showing something else?)

Comment: Ah, the image in Zerobinary99's answer explains much better what the situation for the question asker would be.